# Yii2: How to make position:none for kartik timepicker?

Tags: css, yii2

I need to apply css3 properties to kartik time picker widget tried with

```
   <div style=" position: none;">

    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'checkin_time')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [] )->label(false); ?>?>
    </div>
```

But not able to get it, is there any way so to apply css3 properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `containerOptions` is the array that set the HTML attributes for the main widget container

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'checkin_time')->widget(TimePicker::classname(),
   ['containerOptions' => ['style' => 'position:none;']] )->label(false); ?>
```